# The user with id 123 does not have the right update on item with id 123

Tags: ruby, https, sdk, podio

I'm getting this error when i try to edit an item, i already try authenticating as user using username and password but i still getting this error.

Also i already try searching on my Podio app for any setting, but the one that does not allow users to edit item is unchecked.

**Authorization Method**

```
response = HTTParty.post("https://podio.com/oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=cliendId&client_secret=clientSecret&password=password&username=username",
                          headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
return "OAuth2 #{JSON.parse(response.body)['access_token']}"
```

**Edit item method**

```
response = HTTParty.put("https://api.podio.com/item/123",
                         headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                                    'Authorization': authorization },
                         body: { fields: data }.to_json)
```

Doing this allow me to do anything except edit, when i try to edit any record i get this error all the time.

`PodioForbiddenError: "The user with id 123 does not have the right update on item with id 123"`

Comment: Is authorization is the access token which you received after authentication?

Answer (score 0):

The error states that the authenticated user doesn't have the access to the mentioned item or the app that consisting the item might have the below settings enabled.
`Don't let members edit items in this app`.
You can check this setting in the **App Settings** menu in the **wrench** icon.

Comment: Are you (the authenticated user) able to view the item in Podio UI?